# Strange values in onPreferenceChange method

Tags: java, android, android-preferences

I have an Android app with a preferences screen. The only preference in that screen is a MultiSelectListPreference with four options. I'm trying to implement the `onPreferenceChange` method to update the Preference's summary every time an option changes.

To do this, I'm casting the `newValue` object to a HashSet of Strings, but when I log out the contents of the HashSet, they don't correspond with the values the user selected.

This is my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
    if (preference instanceof MultiSelectListPreference) {
        MultiSelectListPreference pref = (MultiSelectListPreference) preference;
        HashSet<String> values = (HashSet<String>) newValue;
        Log.e("SettingsActivity", values.toString());
    }

    return true;
}
```

And here is the Log message printed out when I select all the four options:

```
07-28 13:13:00.896 31196-31196/com.example.android.theguardiannews E/SettingsActivity:
[ film , environment,  business ,  environment , politics, business]
```

**Edit:** Here is an image of all the possible options:

[image]
Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: can you show a image with preference screen, basicaly i whant a print of all list posibilitys.

Comment: @BrunoFerreira I edited my question with the image you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

So you can try do this inside **onPreferenceChange()** method:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Set<String> selections = sharedPrefs.getStringSet("Your_preference_key", null);
String[] selected = selections.toArray(new String[] {});
Toast.makeText(context, selected[all], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

and for update **sumary** just add this line:

```
Preference pref = findPreference("pref_key");
pref.setSummary(selected[all]);
```

So code probably be like:

```
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs =   PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Set<String> selections = sharedPrefs.getStringSet("Your_preference_key", null);
    String[] selected = selections.toArray(new String[] {});
    Preference pref = findPreference("Your_pref_key");
    pref.setSummary(selected[all]);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that display the values before they are updated? I think that the values are updated after onPreferenceChanged is called, so you are displaying the values before they are updated. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: You are right my bad, just put outside the method and see wath happens.

Comment: you can update sumary outside the method if it Works fine just get selected values and update the sumary.

Comment: But if put it outside the method the summary won't get updated every time the user changed the selected items, right?

Comment: I searched a little more and found a possible way that is put inside **onPreferenceChange() ** because the preferences changes and the method is fired i will update my answer with the correct code.

Comment: @Ale-Jandra try and see if Works.